# How to secure Pybossa completely?

Tags: python, crowdsourcing, pybossa

I want to secure `/project/project1/1/results.json` end point of pybossa.
This end point exposes our results to public without authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the founder of Scifabric, the company that develops PYBOSSA. You can do that using Nginx, as PYBOSSA does not support it out of the box. PYBOSSA has been designed to be an open science/data hub, so all the data is available.

We have a few plugins that have been developed for our customers, that specifically secure some end points. If you want to know more, go to http://scifabric.com and send us an email.

Cheers,

Daniel